# Executing DeferredTask with JAVA GAE sdk

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to execute delayed DeferredTask in Google App Engine (JAVA).

So far here is what I got.

**The task class itself:**

```
public class TestTask implements DeferredTask {


    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.print("test");
    }

}
```

**And the execution:**

```
QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue().add(TaskOptions.Builder.withEtaMillis(10000).payload(new TestTask()));
```

When I run it on the dev server, console output show up right away when task is added to queue, and not after 10 seconds as I wanted :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dev Server typically handles the execution differently. This is detailed in the following section : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push#Java_Push_queues_and_the_development_server

So, it is likely that some of the parameters that you are trying to specify are ignored by the dev server and the task is executed immediately. In case you do not want the task to be executed and prefer that you manually invoke it in the dev server, there is a setting to be provided for the app server as detailed in the note above.

Comment: Read something about that. But is etaMilis defining miliseconds from now or from the initial 1970year date?

Comment: etaMillis() should from the epoch time i.e. 1/1/1970. As per the documentation too, it says "Sets the approximate absolute time to execute. (i.e. etaMillis is comparable with System.currentTimeMillis())." The statement comparable with System.currentTimeMillis() indicates that it is the epoch time.